# Merge cells if is same text

Tags: excel, vba

If column B contains the same text, i want VBA to merge the respective cells as shown in the picture below.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This looks pretty easy!!

```
Sub Macro()
Dim lngRow As Long
For lngRow = ActiveSheet.Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row To 2 Step -1
    If StrComp(Range("B" & lngRow), Range("B" & lngRow - 1), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        If Range("B" & lngRow) <> "" Then
        Range("A" & lngRow & ":" & "A" & lngRow - 1).Merge
        End If
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Before.

[image]

After.

[image]